# If I use wubi to install on the same driver as Windows XP, what will happen?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

Will all XP files be deleted? I'm new to Ubuntu and all I want to know is if those files of XP won't get lost at all.

Comment: With Wubi you use an installer *inside* Windows (`.exe` file, right?), as far as I know, so there's no way to use the regular partitioner, I believe. Instead, it will be installed in a file (`root.disk` if I'm correct) on the NTFS drive.

Comment: But what happens with the XP files, i want to know that.

Comment: Nothing. Wubi is designed to try Ubuntu out without fiddling with your hard drive partition, and yet do have it permanently installed. It fills the gap between a "real" install and the non-persistent Live disc image.

Comment: WUBI install is not supported in newest version of Ubuntu 13.04, as it does not work with Windows 8. Nothing should happen to your XP files. But when you tinker with Operating Systems, you never know. You must have at least two backup copies of every file you have in two different external media like USB drive and DVD.

Comment: qertvdijk:  I think this should be an answer, not a comment so it can be up-voted.  This is a legit question for folks that are looking to go modern from XP but don't find the MS model sustainable or helpful.  Wubi is a great chance to play and test, I would add to the answer that it can be easily uninstalled using the add / remove programs tool.

Comment: @Dennis Done. offtopic: I saw your comment by accident - please make sure to use the '@' to properly mention me so the system will notify me about it. Thanks!

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks for the heads up.  Good advice again.

Answer (score 1):

> Will all XP files be deleted?

No, not with Wubi.

> what happens with the XP files, i want to know that.

Nothing. Wubi is designed to try Ubuntu out without fiddling with your hard drive partition, and yet do have it permanently installed. It fills the gap between a "real" install and the non-persistent Live disc image.

With Wubi you use an installer inside Windows (`.exe` file), so there's no way to use the regular partitioner, I believe. Instead, it will be installed in a file (`root.disk` if I'm correct) on the NTFS drive of your Windows OS.

So, basically, only some files will be added and the Windows bootloader will be configured to have an entry to boot into Ubuntu, installed in the `root.disk` file.